# Is there a way to push notification to flutter app from asp.net core webapi?

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, flutter-notification

I need to sent notification from my website to flutter app using asp.netcore webapi. I had searched for many articles and none of them are with the asp.netcore and flutter combo. Is there a way to that. If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: have you considered Google Firebase or Push Notifications?

Comment: The data I need to display as push message is composed by the webpage which then pass to .netcore api and then it to flutter. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: yes it is doable. Read about it

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam Can you suggest some articles?